# Windows Phone 8.1 application, pivot margins?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, layout, windows-phone-8.1

What are the fonts and margins for PivotTitle and PivotItemHeaders?

I expected them to be [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn596104.aspx), but they are not there.

[image]

Comment: You can take the Pivot and just "Edit Template -> Edit Copy" in eg. Blend. You will get the standard XAML code which represents the Pivot and with some digging, you should get your information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to malte for a hint. Figured out that pivot headers have no margins at all, everything is set by default. Though, PivotItems has margin "19,14.5,0,0". I'm a bit surprised, because i remember a hint from WP 7.5 that all margins should be even, and left one should be 24, i think. Though, neither 19, not 14.5 are even :)

Comment: It is because of scale factor of 1.2 for 480X800 resolution instead of 1.0 in Windows Phone 8.0

Comment: But why 24/1.2 equals 19 I don't know.